# How to recreate such effect using actionscript/pixel bender?

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing, effects, paint, pixel-bender

Effect is generally in mostly vertical with slight horizontal offsets looks like: [image] often used by paintors in sky painting like [here](http://img.lenta.ru/photo/2011/01/29/exhib/pic006.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the source image and desired result, i think a description or example'd be very helpful
as i understand it now, the matrix should have similar values in each column and rather big differences between values in rows (maybe every 2 rows) - to make vertical stripes visible among each other